# Django get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

Tags: python, django

I need to use Korean in the url, but it doesn't work.

[image]

**views.py**

```
class BuildingInfoAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = BuildingData.objects.all()
        serializer = BuildingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
class ReviewListAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = ReviewData.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/buildingdata/', BuildingInfoAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/buildingdata/<str:slug>/', ReviewListAPI.as_view())
]
```

I've tried slug:slug and url with re_path, but these methods says 'page not found'

so I tried str:slug but it says

```
get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'
```

This is slug data in my model.

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, allow_unicode=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
```

'allow_unicode' allows using Korean in the url.

I can't find which code is wrong.

Is there any problem with **views.py** or **urls.py**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `ReviewListAPI`, the `.get(…)` method needs to accept `self`, `request` and `slug` as parameters:

```
class ReviewListAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        queryset = ReviewData.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Since your `.get(…)` method takes a slug, you should likely rewrite the logic and take the slug into account.